# 405 Ошибка при авторизации

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

В веб-сервисе написан код:

*RegistrationController*:

```
[Authorize]
public class RegistrationController : ApiController
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public string Get(string user,string pass)
    {
        if (user=="abc"&&pass=="cba")
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("HomeUser", false);
        return "Home";
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public string Post()
    {
        return "Post";
    }
}
```

*CookieWebClient*:

```
class CookieWebClient : WebClient
{
    public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// This will instanciate an internal CookieContainer.
    /// </summary>
    public CookieWebClient()
    {
        this.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Use this if you want to control the CookieContainer outside this class.
    /// </summary>
    public CookieWebClient(CookieContainer cookieContainer)
    {
        this.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = base.GetWebRequest(address) as HttpWebRequest;
        if (request == null) return base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.CookieContainer = CookieContainer;
        return request;
    }
}
```

В консоли пробую авторизоваться:

```
using (var client = new CookieWebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "user", "abc" },
        { "pass", "cba" },
    };
    client.UploadValues("http://localhost:1401/Get/", "POST", values);

    // If the previous call succeeded we now have a valid authentication cookie
    // so we could download the protected page
    string result = client.DownloadString("http://localhost:1401");
}
```

Но на строке `UploadValues` выдает ошибку: `405 Недопустимый метод`. Как её исправить?

Код WinApiConfig

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{api}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller="Registration",
                api=RouteParameter.Optional,
                id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Независимо от указного анотациями HTTP-метода, Web Api всегда получает простые типы(string, int, long, Guid и некоторые другие) не из тела запроса, а из его адреса.

В клиенте вы передаете параметры user и pass как urlencoded-содержимое тела запроса. Однако в объявлении метода:

```cs
public string Get(string user, string pass)
{
    if (user=="abc"&&pass=="cba")
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("HomeUser", false);
    return "Home";
}
```

Вы неявно указываете, что желаете получить параметры user и pass как часть URL(http://localhost:1401/?user=abc&pass=cba).

Сервер не находит в URL запроса эти два параметра, ну и сообщает о том, что у вас не существует метода Get() не требующего параметров и и поддерживающего POST-запросы.

Для указания параметров в теле запроса, вам нужно создать сложный тип(некий класс; в терминологии Web Api - модель данных):

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Модель хранящая необходимые для аунтентификации данные
/// </summary>
public class AuthentificationInfo
{
    // Web Api поддерживает проверку моделей при помощи анотаций
    // Здесь например указанно что поле требуется, 
    // должно быть не больше 32-х символов,
    // да ещё и сответствовать регулярному выражению "\w+"
    // Порой это очень удобно
    [Required, MaxLength(32), RegularExpression(@"\w+")] 
    public string user { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string pass { get; set; }
}
```

И использовать его как параметр метода веб-сервиса:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public string Get(AuthentificationInfo info)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid && info != null)  // проверяем модель и наличие объекта info
        if (info.user == "abc" && info.pass == "cba")
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("HomeUser", false);

    return "Home";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Какие ограничения есть на модель данных?